# Python sharing data across all modules in django app

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I am using django App and i have several python modules in it.

When user post something then there is userid in it

```
userid = 234
```

From the post i have various modules doing their function.

Now in all those modules i want the `userid` which i can use in log statement.

I really don't want to explicitly supply that id  everywhere.

Is there any way i can set `userid` at the start of `post` and that gets available across all the modules i use for that request

Can i use something like this

```
tdata = threading.local()
tdata.userid = 234
```

Then in `parser_module.py`

```
tdata = threading.local()
log.info(tdata.userid)
```

Or is there any other way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/) (or alternatively, [cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#cookie-session-backend)) if it is per request.

#### Edit

As an alternative if you are not using sessions or cookies, have a look at [Django's low level cache API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/). You can store the value in the cache and access it later.

```
>>> cache.set('userid', 234, 30)
```

Then in another context

```
>>> cache.get('userid')
234
```

Comment: I am not using sessions or cookies its token based authentication

Comment: @JohnKaff you can then possibly use django's cache framework.

Comment: so the cache will per request or per user